# Secondary HDD disconnected

Tags: hard-drive

From time to time my computer (Windows 10) starts working too slowly, and it takes a very long time to turn off.

I am pretty sure that it has something to do with my second HDD. I have the operating system in C:\ but some of the files are stored in D:\ (a second internal disk), and when this happens I can check that the software that uses data from D:\ are the ones that don't respond. Additionaly, I can see in "This PC" that D:\ doesn't appear.

However, when I turn the computer on again everything works perfectly. I don't know if the disk is broken, or if it's a cable connection problem.

I would appreciate very much some ideas of how I can check what is wrong before buying a new HDD if the problem is not fixable.

Thank you!

**Update 28/07/2018:** These are the results of GSmartControl:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads) and run it. Choose second disk and see [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) report attributes, if there are/is red line(s) - it is means HDD going to die.
Most live critical attributes are 5, 196, 197. If they are greater than 0, then you need to replace second disk ASAP

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot of the results. The mentioned values are OK, but not others. Anyway, no lines in red.

Comment: SMART attributes looks good, so drive is OK. How this drive is connected to computer, is it external USB drive or connected internally over SATA slot?

Comment: Internally, over SATA.

Comment: Rarely, but it still a case, SATA connectors get oxidized and loosing contacts. Try to reset it a few times by plugging/un-plugging on the both sides - HDD and motherboard or if you have a spare SATA cable, try to replace it  on second HDD

Comment: If it wouldn't help, let try to find who is in software department is in charge of slowness then. Could you run `perfmon.exe /res` when such slowness would happened and switch to `Disk` then sort columns by `Write`(then Read) and spot process that accessing D drive

Comment: I have changed the cable to a one I wasn't using and I have connected it to another port. I hope it works, otherwise I will try your next advice. Thanks!!!